# Is sefer Avkat Rochel available in English anywhere?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Is the sefer Avkat Rochel by the rishon Rabbeinu Makir ben Abba Mori of Lunel available anywhere in English?

Comment: Hi Mumo and welcome. Like I have posted previously, I do not believe the book is available in English translation.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mumo and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Just to emphasize, the deleted post from zunior, is the correct book in Hebrew. There were many editions printed during the time of the late Rishonim and early Acharonim. The name of the authors father varies across editions and the earliest actually suggest that the author may have been the Rabbeinu Makir who was one of the teachers of Rashi. This is likely because the almost identical tradition comes to us through Machzor Vitry which is attributed to Rashi's grandson. It is another little known gem from the Rishonim.

Comment: For those who don't see it, Yaacov refers to https://hebrewbooks.org/42999